# Simplify / Encode JSON composite key

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, encoding, composite-key

I have a **unique** composite key which is a mixture of a simple stringifed JSON structure concatenated with a Date. It is a fairly complicated looking ID.

`"{ foo: bar}Sun Apr 22 2012 12:58:01 GMT+0100 (BST)"`

I need a process which translates this string to something with a fewer range of characters. Preferably just alpha-numeric. The process does not have to be reversible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just run this through some hash function or use Base64 encoding for the whole id-string.

```
 key = window.btoa( id );
```

[MDN docu link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.btoa)

Comment: @user1349460: Make sure that the IE doesn't support btoa (also see the [browser compability](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.btoa#Browser_compatibility)).

Answer (score 0):

One technique you could use it to use the unix format time instead of `date.toString()`:

```
Math.floor(new Date().getTime()/1000)
```

I tried to find a way of neatly formatting a date but javascript doesn't have anything like [`strftime()`](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=strftime&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CDYQFjAB&url=http://www.cplusplus.com/strftime&ei=9vSTT82zEuSNiAeEq4SnBA&usg=AFQjCNF73iDG7nFsIrRCTA_UbuHGskIcTg&cad=rja) in C/++ or, um, just about every other language.